# Not equals operator not working as expected in SAS proc sql

Tags: sas

I expect the proc sql to return 0 records since the values compared are the same, but it does not return 0 records. What am I missing?

```
DATA TEST;

B='0';
A = put(0,2.);
RUN;
PROC SQL;
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE A NE B;
QUIT;
```

Comment: It should return one record since `'0'` does not equal `' 0'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL is doing what you asked. You asked it to compare `'0'` to `' 0'` and it found that they are different. This is because of the leading blank.  If you had asked SAS to compare `'0'` to `'0 '` it would have found that they matched because of how SAS treats trailing blanks. Try `A = left(put(0,2.));` or `A = put(0,2.-L);` instead.